# Use dplyr::case_when with arguments programmatically

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I'd like to be able to use `dplyr`'s `case_when` in a programmatic way to replace base R `cut()`function.

Currently, case_when can be used with an external argument through NSE like :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

patterns <- list(
  x <= 2 ~ "<=2",
  x <= 4 ~ "2<->4",
  x > 4 ~ ">4"
 )
 x <- 1:10
 case_when(!!!patterns)
```

What I want to do is : use it with another variable, inside a mutate

The idea would be something like this, although I can't figure out how to get it to work :

```
library(dplyr)
patterns_lazy <- list(
  !!quo(x) <= 2 ~ "<=2",
  !!quo(x) <= 4 ~ "2<->4",
  !!quo(x) > 4 ~ ">4"
)
x <- "cyl"
mtcars %>% mutate(ABC = case_when(!!!patterns_lazy))
```

I'd like to be able to define the column (inside a string) that I want to filter on, and retrieve something like this (this example is not working as it's the desired syntax):

```
x <- "cyl"
mtcars %>%
  select(cyl) %>%
  mutate(ABC = case_when(!!!patterns_lazy)) %>%
  head()

  cyl ABC
1   6 >4
2   6 >4
3   4 2<->4
4   6 >4
5   8 >4
6   6 >4
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot use `!!` there:

```
patterns <- list(
  !!quo(x) <= 2 ~ "<=2",
  !!quo(x) <= 4 ~ "2<->4",
  !!quo(x) > 4 ~ ">4"
)
```

1. Neither `list()` nor `~` support quasiquotation.
2. If it did support quasiquotation, you'd need to be careful with operator precedence and wrap your `!!quo()` in parentheses.
3. And finally, that quote to `x` would evaluate to a string and you'd be comparing numbers with strings (in your example it would be `"cyl`) which R will do happily thanks to implicit coercions :/

So you need to use `exprs()` instead of `list()`, and use `x` with the
`.data` pronoun instead of a quote of `x`.

`exprs()` will create a list of unevaluated expressions. Unevaluated
is good: if your formula was evaluated, it would carry an environment
(here the global env) and that environment doesn't contain any of the
data supplied to dplyr, and in particular doesn't have the `.data`
pronoun. On the other hand if the formulas are "context-less", they
get evaluated in the data context which is what we want.

```
patterns_lazy <- exprs(
  .data[[x]] <= 2 ~ "<=2",
  .data[[x]] <= 4 ~ "2<->4",
  .data[[x]] > 4 ~ ">4"
)

x <- "cyl"
pull(mutate(mtcars, case_when(!!!patterns_lazy)))
#>  [1] ">4"    ">4"    "2<->4" ">4"    ">4"    ">4"    ">4"    "2<->4" "2<->4"
#> [10] ">4"    ">4"    ">4"    ">4"    ">4"    ">4"    ">4"    ">4"    "2<->4"
#> [19] "2<->4" "2<->4" "2<->4" ">4"    ">4"    ">4"    ">4"    "2<->4" "2<->4"
#> [28] "2<->4" ">4"    ">4"    ">4"    "2<->4"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with `ifelse`

```
f1 <- function(data, x){
       x <- enquo(x)       
       f2 <- function(y) ifelse(y <= 2, "<=2", ifelse(y <=4, "2<->4", ">4"))

  data %>%
          mutate( ABC = f2(UQ(x)))
 }

f1(mtcars, cyl) %>%
              head()
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   ABC
#1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    >4
#2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    >4
#3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 2<->4
#4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    >4
#5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2    >4
#6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1    >4
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I chose the case_when syntax as I find it more readable than nested ifelse :)