# how to splice arguments in case_when within mutate

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse

`case_when` from the R-package `dplyr` supports [dynamic dots](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/dyn-dots.html).
Hence, I expect it to allow for list-splicing at the `...` parameter.

However, providing a list of two-sided formulas **within `dplyr::mutate`** does not work:

```r
cwl <- list(disp < 100 ~ "<100", disp < 200 ~ "<200", TRUE ~ "high")

datasets::mtcars |> 
  dplyr::mutate(disp2 = case_when(!!!cwl))
```

The resulting error message is:

```
Error in `case_when()`:
! Failed to evaluate the left-hand side of formula 1.
Caused by error:
! object 'disp' not found
```

It seems to be a scoping issue: the formula is apparently not resolved within the right context of `mutate`.

Specifying the formulas **directly** works as expected:

```r
datasets::mtcars |> 
  dplyr::mutate(disp2 = case_when(
    disp < 100 ~ "<100",
    disp < 200 ~ "<200",
    TRUE ~ "high"))
```

Also, it works when I make available all columns in my search path via `attach`:

```r
attach(datasets::mtcars)
case_when(!!!cwl)
```

However, I do not want to `attach` the data as it changes the search path of my R-session.

Any ideas how to make `case_when` + list-splicing work within `mutate`?

Thx a lot,

-m

Comment: It seems to have been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822256/use-dplyrcase-when-with-arguments-programmatically) You can do `cwl <- rlang::exprs(.data[[x]] < 100 ~ "<100", .data[[x]] < 200 ~ "<200", TRUE ~ "high")
x <- "cyl"`

Comment: Ja, you are right. I did not find this question you pointed out. What I like about the proposed solution of @GuedesBF  is that it is more succinct and works without reference to this ominous `.data` pronoun..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we create a list of `expressions`, rather than a list of formulas, it works:

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

cwl <- exprs(disp < 100 ~ "<100", disp < 200 ~ "<200", TRUE ~ "high")

datasets::mtcars |> 
    dplyr::mutate(disp2 = case_when(!!!cwl)) |> 
    select(disp2) |>
    head()
                  disp2
Mazda RX4          <200
Mazda RX4 Wag      <200
Datsun 710         <200
Hornet 4 Drive     high
Hornet Sportabout  high
Valiant            high
```

Comment: Thanks, @GuedesBF, this works nicely, indeed! I have accepted your answer.